# Regex: Matching multiple lines, that begin and end with specific strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file that I'm reading which contains something like the following:

```
13:37:08:634         Verify      
PerformService

13:37:08:634         Buffer      
***********************************************
* INPUTbuffer follows
***********************************************
         ababababa
         cdcdcdcdc


13:37:08:666         Buffer       
***********************************************
* INPUT XML buffer follows
***********************************************
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE SYSTEM 'c:\'>
<App version="3.7.2" payloadID="Wed Dec 11 13:37:08 EST 2013.processId.0.5322738932043712@172.16.57.149" timestamp="Wed Dec 11 13:37:08 EST 2013">


    <header>


        <from>
            <client>
                HTML
            </client>
            <NameAssertion>
//... etc
</App>
```

I'm trying to come up with a regex that can select everything from

```
***********************************************
* INPUT XML buffer follows
***********************************************
```

To `</App>` --

**Update 1 -- working code**

```
bufferBlocks = []
if criteria["buffers"] then
    bufferBlock = ""
    File.foreach("#{options[:source]}") do |li|
        bufferBlock << li if (li['* INPUT XML buffer follows'] .. li[%r(</momentum)])
    end
    bufferBlocks.push(bufferBlock)
end

#... 

buffer << bufferBlocks.shift.to_s.squeeze("\n")
File.write("#{options[:dest]}", buffer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Ruby's "flip-flop" AKA `..` operator shines.

Starting with something like:

```
File.foreach('test.txt') do |li|
  puts li if (li['INPUTbuffer follows'] .. li[%r(</App)])
end
```

If I read your text sample from a file, I get:

```
* INPUTbuffer follows
***********************************************
        ababababa
        cdcdcdcdc


13:37:08:666         Buffer
***********************************************
* INPUT XML buffer follows
***********************************************
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE SYSTEM 'c:\'>
<App version="3.7.2" payloadID="Wed Dec 11 13:37:08 EST 2013.processId.0.5322738932043712@172.16.57.149" timestamp="Wed Dec 11 13:37:08 EST 2013">


    <header>


        <from>
            <client>
                HTML
            </client>
            <NameAssertion>
//... etc
</App>
```

Notice that it's missing the line prior to your "INPUTbuffer..." line. To get it to pick up the line before it requires some regex and a change to how the file is being read. Instead of using `foreach`, which reads line-by-line, the file will have to be read into a buffer, which can cause scalability problems.

A quick and dirty work-around to that is to stuff the delimiting string in front of the content. Something like this:

```
buffer = ('*' * 47) + "\n"
File.foreach('test.txt') do |li|
  buffer << li if (li['INPUTbuffer follows'] .. li[%r(</App)])
end

puts buffer
```

Which now outputs what you want, but cheats a tiny bit. The output now looks like:

```
***********************************************
* INPUTbuffer follows
***********************************************
         ababababa
         cdcdcdcdc
...
```

I mentioned scalability problems. Imagine what would happen to your system if you tried to read a file that wasn't a couple hundred lines, but thousands or millions. Pulling that into a buffer prior to searching, can make your code, or machine, slow down to the point of unusability. This is a situation seen when code moves from development into production, where the development test files were stripped down to their essence, then suddenly the code was seeing full-blown DB dumps, or logs, that were in the GB range.

Instead, using `foreach`, or one of its work-alikes, this code will selectively pull the lines needed and append them to a buffer. If multiple blocks exist in the file, they'll be captured too, without additional code. In that case, how to insert additional header lines and/or process the blocks is left for you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing reply! This seems to have worked, except I get all of the blank lines as well.  I've updated my original post - can you see what's wrong with my Ruby code now?

Comment: My mistake - the above comment was due to bad code on my part (which wasn't included in my snippet).